# Function, a small change

Tags: delphi

here's the code in Delphi:

```
function Perfect(x: Integer): Integer;
var
  i, a: Integer;
begin
  i := 1;
  a := 0;

  while i <= x div 2 do
  begin
    if (x mod i = 0) then
      a := a + i;
    i := i + 1;
  end;

  if x = a then
    Result := x;
end;
```

Basically, it's a function that shows [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) from given interval. I created a loop for to show these numbers but I have a problem because it also shows some random numbers when it's not a perfect number. So let's say I have [1;7] and then console shows that:

```
1969410929
1969410929
1969410929
1969410929
1969410929
6
1969410929
```

What can I do to show only right numbers?

Comment: Have you noticed the warning *"W1035 Return value of function 'Perfect' might be undefined"* which your compiler reported ?

Comment: There may be 2 reasons why he hasn't noticed that warning @TLama. 1. He may not follow the "0 warnings is OK, everything else is not" rule, or 2. He may have a too old Delphi compiler that mayhaps doesn't have that warning (though most likely 1)

Comment: The function should be renamed to `function IsPerfect ( x: integer ): Boolean` and `for x:=1 to 7 do is IsPerfect (x) then WriteLn (x);`

Comment: @Lasse: IIRC, that compiler warning has been around since Delphi 2 or 3 at least. This is a case of either having hints and warnings turned off or of ignoring them.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is failing to set the return value if the number is not perfect. In that scenario the returned value is ill defined. You must always set the return value. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Function_Declarations):

> If the function exits without assigning a value to Result or the function name, then the function's return value is undefined.

Since a function must return a value, your function is in a bind. What to return in case the value is not perfect? There is no good choice in my view. You do not need to return the number since you already know it. You passed it to the function after all.

So, you should change the design of the function to return a boolean indicating whether or not the number was perfect:

```
function IsPerfect(x: Integer): Boolean;
var
  i, sum: Integer;
begin
  sum := 0;
  for i := 1 to x div 2 do
    if x mod i = 0 then
      inc(sum, i);

  Result := x = sum;
end;
```

The code to call the function runs like this:

```
for i := 1 to 1000 do
  if IsPerfect(i) then
    Writeln(i);
```

**Output**

```
6
28
496
```

Answer (score 2):

... "it also shows some random numbers when it's not a perfect number".

The reason for that is that you don't set the `Result` "variable" when it's not a perfect number. If you create a function that doesn't set the `Result` variable in *all* cases, the result of calling it will be undefined in those cases. Random describes it, though it's probably some kind of system, even if the system is just "whatever was left in memory where the `Result` variable was placed".

You need to determine what to return if it's not a perfect number, and make either of the following code changes:

```
Result := <what to return if not?>;
if x = a then
    Result := x;
```

or this:

```
if x = a then
    Result := x
else
    Result := <what to return if not?>;
```

Comment: Alright, I understand that. But what if I want to show only perfect numbers. So for example the console output for [1;7] is: 6. Not (for result:= 0) 0 0 0 0 0 6 0. How can I do it?

Comment: The problem with that is that you already called the function. That function *has* to return something. You can make up a magic return value, like 0 or -1 that means "is not a perfect number", but the function *has* to and *will* return something. If you simply output the result of calling it, you *will* get the same number of printed values as the number of times you called it. The filter to only output perfect numbers have to be placed outside of that function.

Comment: I asked this because I have to make it as a VCL application. http://pastebin.com/PqnCwvbn
It works but shows these '0' as not-perfect numbers. I guess I have to change this function to procedure but then command IntToStr doesn't work. I don't really know what to do to make it work as I want.

Comment: You can make a `TryGet...` fashion like function which will return a boolean value to indicate success and the value will return to an output parameter. Something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/Gnv8tTNq).

Comment: @TLama `TryGet` is a nice idea, but when `TryGetPerfect ( Xin : Integer; out Xout : Integer ): Boolean` returns `true` then you will have the value from `Xin` in `Xout` - a value doubler :o)

Comment: TryGet isn't right here. The out parameter is needless. It can be ignored.

Comment: @SirRufo, d'oh, sure. That would be brainless :-) I was somehow automatically assuming that the input value changes without looking on the function context.